# HTML5 positioning

Tags: html

is possible to make a specific element about 5px longer that it would automatically be? because my article element has a video element which sticking out of the given space a bit, while I could just set the height manually I thought it would be better to have it set itself automatically (like it normally does) only adding about 5px. Any Help?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle.net or your html/css?

Comment: have you tried to give a `height:auto` to the article element + `margin-bottom:5px` to your video element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but have you tried giving it a padding-bottom of 5px?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dynamic width to set the width of your contained element.

Eg.

```
article {
   width:300px;
 }
contained-element{
   width:95%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give `padding-bottom:5px` to your `<article>` elements, & make `height:auto` for both elements, then `<article>` element will expand as per height with 5px at bottom.

Comment: thanks mate! but vdwijngaert replied first

Answer (score 0):

Am not very much sure what are you asking about but if it's regarding fitting your video in a div for that  you can create a wrapper class such as

```
.wrapper-div {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 20%;
height: 0;
}
```

then have the child element inside it

```
.element-to-load{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to the div to expand if the video is larger than the article.

To do this you just need to:

**1)** Give the Outer Div a `height:auto` - and a `min-height:` 
   **2)** Give the Inner Div a `margin-bottom` of `5px`

[**Check out this Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Pjn/)

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

Just set the CSS for that element be (use the actual pixel width and height):

```
height: 25px;
width: 50px;
```

and the height and the width will be forced to be that height and width.

Although if possible try to use 'em' so that it is automatically responsive.